# How to set External_User_Id in OneSignal using web(js)?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, android-studio, onesignal

I noticed that OneSignal is creating a unique **player_id** and adding a column in its database when my web app is loaded for the first time by any user.

I'm trying to add a custom **external_user_id** into the same one signal DB field using below code (as per [OneSignal docs](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/external-user-ids)):

```
<script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js" ></script>
<script>
let externalUserId = "123456789"; 

OneSignal.push(function() {
  OneSignal.setExternalUserId(externalUserId);
});
</script>
```

But somehow, the **external_user_id** field is still set to empty.

So I added the below code to it.

```
<script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js" ></script>
<script>
let externalUserId = "123456789"; 

window.OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
OneSignal.push(function() {
    OneSignal.init({
        appId: "xoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxo",
    });
});

OneSignal.push(function() {
  console.log("triggering");
  OneSignal.setExternalUserId(externalUserId);
  console.log("triggering");
});
```

It has no errors, yet ***external_user_id*** is still not updated.

This is the OneSignal code I have added to my *Android Studio*

```
package com.appgrep.xoxoxo;

import android.app.Application;

public class OneSignal extends Application {

    private static final String ONESIGNAL_APP_ID = "xoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxo";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // OneSignal Initialization
        com.onesignal.OneSignal.initWithContext(this);
        com.onesignal.OneSignal.setAppId(ONESIGNAL_APP_ID);
    }
}
```

I just am trying to add External_User_Id in OneSignal using [Web (JS)](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/external-user-ids)
Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Amit's suggestion to get a user id**

```
var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
 OneSignal.push(function() {
    OneSignal.getUserId(function(userId) {
      console.log("OneSignal User ID:", userId);
      $("#some").text(userId);
    });
  });
```

the `getUserId` function is not triggereing.

I can do like:

```
var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];

OneSignal.push(function() {
  OneSignal.on('subscriptionChange', function (isSubscribed) {
      OneSignal.push(function() {
        OneSignal.getUserId(function(userId) {
          console.log("OneSignal User ID:", userId);
        });
      });
    });
  });
```

But in my scenario, there is no subscription, all users are registered in one signal as soon as their open the web app and the subscription is auto-ticked.

[image: OneSignal user's screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I have tried setting external_user_id using web(js) and it's working fine without problem.

#### Requirement

- Working Onesignal implementation
- Subscribe to Notification

Now just open the Dev console and paste the following code to set external_user_id

```
let externalUserId = "123456789"; // You will supply the external user id to the OneSignal SDK
OneSignal.push(function() {
      OneSignal.setExternalUserId(externalUserId);
    });
```

Now check if external_user_id is set or not

```
OneSignal.push(function() {
  OneSignal.getExternalUserId().then(function(externalUserId){
    console.log("externalUserId: ", externalUserId);
  });
});
```

[See screenshot of dev console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVDrZ.png)

alternatively, visit OneSignal dashboard and check the user, you will external_user_id just make sure to make external_user_id column visible,
[Check external_user_id in dashboard image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iz9m.png)

When done with your testing remove the demo external_user_id

```
OneSignal.push(function() {
  OneSignal.removeExternalUserId();
});
```

Documentation: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/external-user-ids

#### Just keep in mind if you are setting External_user_id through Android SDK and want to update it on web

> Warning - Android SDK Data Synchronization
>
> The OneSignal Android SDKs leverage cacheing on external_user_id and
> Data Tags.
>
> If setting external_user_id through the Edit device API Endpoint, then
> use the same endpoint to remove the external_user_id upon the user
> logging out of the app.
>
> The removeExternalUserId method will not work unless the
> external_user_id is set first with the setExternalUserId method on
> Android.
>
> This is only applicable on the OneSignal Android Mobile App SDKs.

### Use the following code

Replace <APP_ID> with your app app id of the page

```
<script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js" ></script>

<script>
  window.OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
  OneSignal.push(function() {
    OneSignal.init({
      appId: "<APP_ID>",
    });
  });

OneSignal.getUserId((userId) => {
    if (userId == null){
        alert("Subscribe to Notification First")
        return
    }
    alert(`Player id: is ${userId}`);
});
</script>
```

Comment: You are using player_id from onesignal to update ext_id, But how do i get player_id in the first place.?

Comment: When you subscribe to a notification player id is automatically created for each user you don't need to create it,  In my code, I am not referencing the player id anywhere, these snippets are directly copy-paste from the documentation. Just make sure you have a working OneSignal setup.

Comment: No, My question was, How do I even get the player_id from one signal to web in the first place.?

Comment: try OneSignal.getUserId() you will get the player_id. Keep in mind you can not change player_id. external_user_id is separate from player_id, you can set and use external_user_id in your code.

Comment: I tried the code mentioned above in the update question,, but its not return any user-id

Comment: user_id is returned if you check the promise it returned, use the following code to log it 
OneSignal.getUserId(function(userId){console.log(userId);});

screenshot https://imgur.com/a/RCv89sP

Comment: @Harry are you trying to run web(js) code inside Android studio?

Comment: No, I m running the code in my website. Its actually a web app. Made it with html, css, js and php, convereted in android studio with onesignal to push notificaions. 

if you can please wanna take a look at it, i can share the code with you ?

Comment: I used your code Amit, yet I couldn't able to retrieve player_id from one signal. can you tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: do share the URL of your webpage so I can look at it.

Comment: [This](https://rapidfuel.tharunatwork.com/user/v2.5/index.php) is the welcome page where the player id gets generated in one signal and I kept the code to get the player_id from one signal in js.

Comment: On the page, I don't see OneSignal SDK being loaded also no service worker is registered,   how you are going to access OneSignal functions and methods when you don't load them, Please go through the documentation of OneSignal once again, 

In my answer I stated two requirements, please first complete them only after that you can use the code provided by me not before.

here is documentation, how to load OneSignal on web https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-quickstart

Comment: I did exactly what [it said](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-custom-code-setup). I signed up, at the time of integration and added the site as per the docs. Here's the [screenshot](https://ibb.co/5sXBFBF) of the .js file added in hosting. And here's the [screenshot](https://ibb.co/y0DQmfh) of one signal code in the file. Yet, Nothing on the load of that page.

Comment: @Harry I have updated the answer please use that code, make sure to replace <APP_ID> with your app id, Do make sure you are using the right app id issued for your specific subdomain,

Answer (score -1):

I think it's not possible through web buddy.

What you are trying to do is to update a field in onesignl using website. Which i don't think one signal let's you do.

Comment: I don't understand, if it's not possible through the web then what's the point of "web(js)" code in the [OneSignal's doc](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/external-user-ids)?